# Differentiation that involves determinant and vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

How can i calculate following?

$\frac{d}{dR'} {(|\vec{R}-\vec{R'}|)^{-1}}$

I tried this but I'm not sure this a valid method:

1. let $\vec{R}-\vec{R'} = \vec{u}$, then
2. $-\vec{dR'}= \vec{du}$

following chain rule we get:
 3. $\frac{d}{dR'} = \frac{d}{du} \times \frac{du}{dR'} $

it follows from (2), we have:

4. $du = -dR' => \frac{du}{dR'} = -1$

so we get
$-u^{-2} \times -1 = \frac{1}{u^{2}} $

Comment: $\vec R$ and $\vec R'$ are elements of $\mathbb R^n$? Where do determinants come into play?

Comment: Yep, they are elements of $\mathbb R^3$. $R'$ symbolizes position of charge and R is the point of observation through origin. So $|R-R'|$ is distance between charge and point of observation

Comment: So you'r really just looking for the gradient of the function $$\frac{1}{|\vec R-(x,y,z)|}?$$

Comment: Yep. In terms of cartesian coordinates it is easy. But im kinda trying develop concept in my mind. We use spherical coordinates a lot so im trying to be close to it. I try to take it other way, make some coordinate transformation to solve problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to treat 3d vector variables as scalar variables in a couple of places there, and that doesn't work.

First, as Alex S alludes to, the concept of $\frac{df}{d\vec v}$, where $f(\vec v)$ is a vector-valued function has to be interpreted as the gradient. As such, the differential notation is highly misleading, so it is generally expressed as $\nabla f$ or sometimes $D_{\vec v}f$, but not as $\frac{df}{d\vec v}$.

Second, as $\vec u$ and $\vec R'$ are both vectors, $\frac {d\vec u}{d\vec R'}$ represents the derivative of a function from $\Bbb r^3$ to $\Bbb r^3$. I suspect you have yet to encounter such derivatives, but if you have, then you should know that they are $3\times 3$ matrices, not scalar values. Now in this case it is just $-I$, so you were not that far off, but you should be clear on the difference. As above, the differential-ratio notation is not preferred. This one is most commonly denoted by $D_{\vec R'}\vec u$

The chain-rule does indeed apply here, even though the derivatives are of different forms. So $$D_{\vec R'}|\vec u|^{-1} = D_{\vec R'}\vec uD_{\vec u}|\vec u|^{-1}$$.

Third is that $|\vec u| = \sqrt{\vec u \cdot \vec u}$, where $\cdot$ is the inner product, so define $f(x) = 1/\sqrt x$, then $|\vec u|^{-1} = f(\vec u \cdot \vec u)$, which by an application of the multi-variate chain rule again gives us $$D_{\vec u}|\vec u|^{-1} = f'(\vec u \cdot \vec u)D_{\vec u}(\vec u \cdot \vec u)$$ Now $f'(x) = -\frac12x^{-3/2}$, and you can see from coordinate calculation that $D_{\vec u}(\vec u \cdot \vec u) = 2\vec u$.

So if you put these pieces together, you can see what the derivative really is: 
$$\begin{align}D_{\vec R'}|\vec u|^{-1} &= D_{\vec R'}\vec uD_{\vec u}|\vec u|^{-1}\\&=(-I)\left(f'(\vec u \cdot \vec u)D_{\vec u}(\vec u \cdot \vec u)\right)\\&=-\left(-\frac12(\vec u \cdot \vec u)^{-3/2}\right)(2\vec u)\\&=\frac{\vec u}{|\vec u|^3}\\&=\frac{\vec R - \vec R'}{|\vec R - \vec R'|^3}\end{align}$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I treated $\vec{dR}$ as $dR \times \vec{a_{R}}$. So $dR= |\vec{dR}|$. What is the subject name for that kind of manipulations?

Comment: As a method for calculating the derivative you said you are after? The name would be "Invalid". There is such a thing as a directional derivative, so if you have some **fixed** direction $\vec a$, you can find rates of change in just that direction, but that is just 1d functions times a vector, and is ordinary calculus, not multivariate.

Comment: I mean derivatives which involves matrices, such as from $\Bbb r^3$ to $\Bbb r^3$ as your answer suggests